# How to create a good search that includes matching records

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I don't know how to explain this in the title, I'm experiencing a problem where I'm searching that when I search for a typical query such as `united kingdom` and records include records that have `united states` which I do not need it to be included in the query result, even when searching `new york` I get some records returned from `york` (in England).

Another, when searching `maidstone`, the query returns no records whatsoever, but in the database it exists.

I need to problem solve this query, it should search the rows matching the inputted query and remove them that match against the options -- when I say options, I mean as `rec.column_name = etc...`.

When searching `united kingdom`:

```
WHERE  ( MATCH (rec.street_name, rec.city, rec.state, rec.country) AGAINST ('united kingdom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
         OR ( rec.street_name = 'united kingdom' 
              OR rec.city = 'united kingdom' 
              OR rec.state = 'united kingdom'
              OR rec.country = 'united kingdom'
            )
       ) AND ( rec.visible_listing = 1 AND rec.marked_delete = 0 AND rec.is_archive = 0 )
```

When searching `maidstone`:

```
WHERE  ( MATCH (rec.street_name, rec.city, rec.state, rec.country) AGAINST ('maidstone' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
         OR ( rec.street_name = 'maidstone' 
              OR rec.city = 'maidstone' 
              OR rec.state = 'maidstone'
              OR rec.country = 'maidstone'
            )
       ) AND ( rec.visible_listing = 1 AND rec.marked_delete = 0 AND rec.is_archive = 0 )
```

This is the overall records in the table:

```
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
| street_name        | city          | state          | country        | visible_listing | marked_delete | is_archive |
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
| Mill Hill          | Dover         | Kent           | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Penmaes            | Rhayader      | Powys          | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Essex St           | Jersey City   | Hudson         | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Vesey St           | New York      | New York       | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| E Broadway         | Manhattan     | New York       | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Cowdray Square     | Dover         | Kent           | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          1 |
| Falsgrave Crescent | York          | England        | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Tait Ave           | Sanger        | California     | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Morton Ave         | Parsons       | Kansas         | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| N Washington St    | Clinton       | Missouri       | United States  |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Lower Barngoose    | Carn Brea     | Cornwall       | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Moorwell Dr        | Shepherdswell | Kent           | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Elm Grove          | Maidstone     | Kent           | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Manse Rd           | Killin        | Stirling       | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Muirkirk Dr        | Glasgow       | Glasgow City   | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
| Alveston Ave       | Harrow        | Greater London | United Kingdom |               1 |             0 |          0 |
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
```

How do I make a good search query that returns non-false data?

Comment: Why do you combine regular searched with FULLTEXT searches?

Comment: The first lines, after the WHERE, is a MATCH condition that can be used only on fields that have a FULLTEXT index. The lines below, starting with OR, are regular conditions that check for an exact match (checks if the field contains a literal string). It doesn't seem useful to combine these.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the point when I was trying to make a "good search", I removed this and used your solution of using double quotes. Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the search string inside double quotes: `'"united kingdom"'` for an exact match.

If you want to search for both words, but not necessarily adjacent to each other, you can use the + operator: `'+united +kingdom'`.

Note that the searches will be case sensitive if you use a binary collation for the columns you search in.